# Playing SMIL on Android 2.1

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1, smil

Is it possible to invoke native SMIL player on Android 2.1? Can you please provide a code sample or a pointer to relevant info?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in some cases there a is player for SMIL files. Though I could not find a way (impossible?) to launch it as it is not a part of the official SDK

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to invoke native SMIL player on Android 2.1?

I do not believe there is a "native SMIL player" in any version of Android.

It is possible that the WebKit browser can play SMIL. I believe the desktop versions can, but I have no idea if that was stripped out or not for the Android mobile edition. Try opening a SMIL file from the Internet in the Browser application. If it works, you may be able to use the `WebView` widget to play SMIL files in your own application. If the Browser does not seem to recognize SMIL, you will have to search for a third-party SMIL player, if there is one.

Comment: Looks like there is Slideshow player, which is a part of MMS application and is not part of the official SDK.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556633/parse-application-smil-mms-mime-type-on-android