# How to use SMIL file in Android development

Tags: java, android, media-player, smil

My requirment is to make Media player based on SMIL language on android platform
is it possible to use SMIL  file in android?

Thanks Advace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 'out of the box' (although you didn't tell us exactly which android box you might be in).

But there are several other questioners asking this very question, leading me to believe this belongs in the "do my homework for me" category. And a quick search would have revealed this answer:

[Parse application/smil MMS MIME type on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556633/parse-application-smil-mms-mime-type-on-android)

...where the first answer includes a link to a Java based SMIL player. Always search before asking. Thanks!